# gcc ARM produces incorrect code - how to correct

Tags: gcc, arm

gcc ARM for STM32F407 micro

The following function is used as a sanity check in FreeRtosTCP

```
UBaseType_t bIsValidNetworkDescriptor( const NetworkBufferDescriptor_t * pxDesc )
{

    uint32_t offset = ( uint32_t ) ( ((const char *)pxDesc) - ((const char *)xNetworkBuffers) );

    if( ( offset >= (uint32_t)(sizeof( xNetworkBuffers )) ) || ( ( offset % sizeof( xNetworkBuffers[0] ) ) != 0 ) )
        return pdFALSE;

    return (UBaseType_t) (pxDesc - xNetworkBuffers) + 1;
}
```

The line in question is --->   offset >= (uint32_t)(sizeof( xNetworkBuffers ))

gcc produces a bhi instruction after the cmp instead of a bhs.

If tries casting both as shown in the code above but nothing seems to get the bhs instruction to be used.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Joe

Comment: Adding that assembly code will also be helpful @JHinkle

Comment: Or better add a fully compilable code (also called a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you have that, you can do experiments to find a workaround with the [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org).

Comment: you also don't need to use so many unnecessary parentheses which reduce readability

Answer (score 2):

Well knowing the exact size of the xNetworkBuffers array compiler can simply optimize it. Being curious I gave it a try. Following is the code with little modifications and the asm output and the explanation:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct abc {
    char data[10];
}NetworkBufferDescriptor_t;
NetworkBufferDescriptor_t xNetworkBuffers[5];

int bIsValidNetworkDescriptor( const NetworkBufferDescriptor_t * pxDesc )
{

    uint32_t offset = ( uint32_t ) ( ((const char *)pxDesc) - ((const char *)xNetworkBuffers) );

    if( ( offset >= (uint32_t)(sizeof( xNetworkBuffers )) ) || ( ( offset % sizeof( xNetworkBuffers[0] ) ) != 0 ) )
        return 0;

    return (int) (pxDesc - xNetworkBuffers) + 1;
}
```

and the asm output is:

```
bIsValidNetworkDescriptor:
    @ Function supports interworking.
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 16
    @ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    str fp, [sp, #-4]!
    add fp, sp, #0
    sub sp, sp, #20
    str r0, [fp, #-16]
    ldr r3, [fp, #-16]
    ldr r2, .L5
```

> ```
>   sub r3, r3, r2
>   str r3, [fp, #-8]
>   ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
>   cmp r3, #49
>   bhi .L2
> ```

```
    ldr r1, [fp, #-8]
    ldr r3, .L5+4
    umull   r2, r3, r1, r3
    lsr r2, r3, #3
    mov r3, r2
    lsl r3, r3, #2
    add r3, r3, r2
    lsl r3, r3, #1
    sub r2, r1, r3
    cmp r2, #0
    beq .L3
.L2:
    mov r3, #0
    b   .L4
.L3:
    ldr r3, [fp, #-16]
    ldr r2, .L5
    sub r3, r3, r2
    asr r2, r3, #1
    mov r3, r2
    lsl r3, r3, #1
    add r3, r3, r2
    lsl r1, r3, #4
    add r3, r3, r1
    lsl r1, r3, #8
    add r3, r3, r1
    lsl r1, r3, #16
    add r3, r3, r1
    lsl r3, r3, #2
    add r3, r3, r2
    add r3, r3, #1
.L4:
    mov r0, r3
    add sp, fp, #0
    @ sp needed
    ldr fp, [sp], #4
    bx  lr
.L6:
    .align  2
.L5:
```

In the block quoted asm code you can see that it is comparing with 49 not 50 (which is the actual size of xNetworkBuffers) so the conclusion I got is

```
offset >= (uint32_t)(sizeof( xNetworkBuffers ))
```

is also equal to

```
offset > (uint32_t)(sizeof( xNetworkBuffers ) - 1) )
```

and in that case compiler can use BHI producing the same results

Comment: @JHinkle can you please confirm your scenario and if it is the same and any of the answers solved your question than kindly mark that answer correct otherwise please add  the extra information as requested in the comments on the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the code generated by GCC is correct, technically speaking.  `offset` cannot be larger than `INT_MAX`, because this is the maximum value representable in `ptrdiff_t` on this architecture.

You can compute the difference like this:

```
    uintptr_t offset = (uintptr_t)pxDesc - (uintptr_t)xNetworkBuffers;
```

This is still implementation-defined, but it will avoid the overflow problem.